# How to insert text with href to record view's field In sugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

How to insert text with href to record view's field In SugarCRM

We want to give link to any text or record

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- What's been attempted?  Where's your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    custom/modules/your_module/metadata/detailviewdefs.php

    array (

       'name' => 'temp_c',

       'label' => 'LBL_TEMP',

       'customCode' => '{if $fields.temp_1_c.value}

        <a href="{$fields.temp_1_c.value}" target="_blank">

        <img src="imgname.png" alt="Img" width="25" height="25" />

        </a>

        {/if} />',


    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

simply create URL type field: Following is the code:

```
$dictionary['module_name']['fields']['website'] =  array (
    'labelValue' => 'Website',
    'required' => false,
    'name' => 'website',
    'vname' => 'LBL_WEBSITE',
    'type' => 'url',
    'massupdate' => '0',
    'default' => '',
    'no_default' => false,
    'comments' => '',
    'help' => '',
    'importable' => 'true',
    'duplicate_merge' => 'disabled',
    'duplicate_merge_dom_value' => '0',
    'audited' => true,
    'reportable' => true,
    'unified_search' => false,
    'merge_filter' => 'disabled',
    'len' => '255',
    'size' => '20',
    'dbType' => 'varchar',
    'gen' => '',
    'link_target' => '_blank',
);
```

File location should be: *custom\Extension\modules\module_name\Ext\Vardefs\sugarfield_website.php*